# Rails with Postgres - Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm using PG for Rails development. Every time I create a new app, it creates a default database.yml file that sets the "username" to the name of the app. I have to go in and chnage the username for the DB to a username that already exists, or create that role on PG. I'd like to skip this if possible.

Is there any way to configure PG to allow interaction from any role, despite the name, so I can disregard this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to allow login to Postgres with any arbitrary username, and I think it would be a security risk if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure postgres to allow connections with any role with default authentication method.

There may be a way to map app names to DB roles. Fro details read this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html to find suitable auth methods.